# How to fix "TypeError: $ is not a function" error in WordPress custom page?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I created custom WordPress page via plugin where I want to toggle on/off comments using this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">                 
  $("comment_switch").click(function () {
    $("comments").toggleClass("hidden");
  });
</script>
```

I placed it inside the `<body>` tag. To generate `<head>` tag I used standard WordPress function `wp_head();`. When I check the source code of the page I can see in head section `<script src="http://10.1.1.6/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2" type="text/javascript">` which I thought would be enough to use jQuery.

Could someone help me to make the jQuery code work? The whole source code of the page could be found [here](http://pastebin.com/DLB7wQ8V)

Comment: `body` ok but *body* at the beginning (when the DOM is still not read) or before `</body>`?

Comment: Have you checked the path of the jQuery file and made sure it is valid

Comment: More likely then not jquery is running in noConflict mode. try to substitute jQuery for $ to confirm

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're probably missing some `.` class markup and the **DOM ready function**

```
jQuery(function($) { // DOM is now ready and jQuery's $ alias sandboxed

    $(".comment_switch").on("click", function () {
        $(".comments").toggleClass("hidden");
    });

});
```

Comment: Yes, yes :-) You were right with both issues. I didn't 100% checked the code from http://stackoverflow.com/a/3102240/250422 I can understand the dots being missing but could you explain why I had to use `jQuery(function($)`? Thank you.

Comment: @Radek Most likely because wordpress is using `$.noConflict` which makes `$` not equal to `jQuery`. you could probably instead just replace `$` with `jQuery` to make your code work, assuming it is immediately before the closing body tag. The code in this answer makes it work because it's using `jQuery` on the outside, then accepting the passed argument (which just so happens to be `jQuery`) with a name of `$` which you then used inside your code.

Comment: @Radek what I did is : get `window.jQuery` assign as reference argument the `$`, that way inside the function the `$` is assigned to window jQuery reference. it's a low level way that in 90% of cases is worthy the noConflict one. It prevents you from typing all over again `jQuery` instead of the reference `$`.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Right, but you're also doing more than that. your assuming that the code needs to be inside a document ready, which is incorrect in this case due to the location of the script. The whole problem is `$ !== jQuery`, which your code solves by using the argument assigned to `jQuery(function(here){})`

Comment: @Radek It is, unless $.noConflict is being used, which is very common with wordpress.

Comment: @KevinB sure, does both, most of users using WP were amazed that they could define `jQuery(function($){` and was working in all cases without the use of noConf. and `jQuery` all over the place :)

Comment: How can I find out if `$.noConflict` was used?

Comment: @Radek Is `$` equivalent to `jQuery`? if not, then it's a pretty good bet that it is being used, that or something is overriding `$`.

Comment: @Radek you can always inspect your console for the `scripts` being used in your page and *find* the desired match. Additionally it's no way (ok,99,99%) that another library is registered to the window Object as `jQuery`, so using the `jQuery` Object call and referencing it inside the arg function as `$` leaves you hands-free-to-go ;) with the dearest alias.

Comment: OK guys, I have no idea what you are taking about. It seems to me too deep for me. Could you recommend any reading for me? Thanks to both of you.

Comment: @Radek Interesting reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983150/jquery-dollar-sign-as-function-argument

Answer (score -2):

you need to encapsulate your javascript in function that executes on DOM ready event

```
<script type="text/javascript">                 
 $(function () {
   $("comment_switch").click(function () {
    $("comments").toggleClass("hidden");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: $ is not a function, but you still calling it.

Comment: @user3502626 i don't know how you are able to  make statements like that, `$` is a shortCut to jQuery and jQuery is a function so is `$`

Comment: I tested your code but, it did not work: `$(function(){...})` but, `jQuery(function($){...})` worked. People say $ is an alias of jQuery but, the alias did not work.

Comment: that's because of how you may have configured your jquery in a `noConflict` setting. just because you don't understand the basics of how something works, you can't go around putting -1 answers.

Comment: This is not about me. This is about WordPress. So, like you said, a user **may have configured his jquery in a noConflict setting** So, [maybe] it's the case of Wordpress. So generally, your code gives the _$ is not a function_ error in WordPress.

Answer (score -2):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">                 
 (function () { // 1) remove the "$"
   $(".comment_switch").click(function () { // 2) add "." if this a class or "#" // if it is an id
    $(".comments").toggleClass("hidden");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please, add a description of the solution you are proposing.