# Workpress Enqueue Script Issue - Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, wordpress, typeerror

My javascript works on my static site, but when I enqueue the js in my wordpress functions.php it is giving me are error.  I can't figure what I am doing wrong.

Here is the Wordpress Enqueue code

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'smooth', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/smooth-scroll.js', '', '', true);
```

Here is the Error Message

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "TypeError: $ is not a function" error in WordPress custom page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295538/how-to-fix-typeerror-is-not-a-function-error-in-wordpress-custom-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery in WordPress runs in noConflict mode, which means you cannot use the $ alias, you have to use the full jQuery instead.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
// $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
      // your code here 
} );
```

Comment: Brilliant! - thank you thank you thank you!  that was driving me nuts

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to wrap all your jQuery code with anonymous function.

```js
(function ($) {
    // your code here
}) (jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the $ identifier does not work in wordpress.

Try replacing all your "$" with "jQuery",and see if that works.